# Como mejorar esta linea de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes, tengo esta linea de código, funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de remover todos los `.parent` de alguna forma

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("input").val($(this).text());
```

Comment: Una alternativa puede ser `querySelector`, pero, sin el HTML es difícil darte un ejemplo.

Comment: @Mauricio Deberías poner eso como respuesta, pero me parece que no sería algo trivial porque de momento no se pueden seleccionar ancestros

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, gracias, pero, la razón por la que creado un comentario es porque no considero que sea una respuesta completa _no es que tema a los votos negativos_, pero prefiero agregar respuestas con mas valor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo ▼:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("input").val($(this).text());
```

Una *mejora* sería ▼:

```
$(this).parents().eq(3).find("input").val($(this).text());
```

<sub>Véase [**`.parents()`**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) y [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) para más información.</sub>

Comment: mil gracias, funciona perfecto, lei las referencias que pusiste gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 4):

Usa [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) en combinación con el tipo de elemento o clase que quieras seleccionar. `closest` te devolverá el primer elemento ancestro que cumpla la condición del selector.

Un ejemplo de como funciona:

```js
$("span").on("click", function() {

  $(this).closest("table").find("input").val( $(this).text() );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span>Pulsa aquí</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span>No, mejor aquí</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de `.parents()` de jQuery.

te dejo un ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});//elemento this
  $("span").parents("ul").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
body * {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
  <ul>ul (grandparent)
    <li>li (direct parent)
      <span>Elemento this</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```